# htaccess prevent direct access to path and override with another

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security

There are two parts to my question...

A. What .htaccess should I place in a root folder, in order to prevent ALL DIRECT access to ALL sub-folders & files

B. After doing that, is there a way to place another .htaccess file inside a specific folder (within the root folder) in order to override the first root .htaccess rule

in example :

I would like to prevent all direct access to the `blog` sub-directories

```
blog/posts
blog/files
```

with a single .htaccess file placed in the root directory

But I still want the following to be accessible

```
blog/js
blog/css
```

using a specific .htacess file to be placed within each of those

Thanks!

update - I actually found an answer to A (deny from all), but still how can I override the deny from all placed in the root folder, with a specific .htaccess in a specific sub-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place this directive in `/blog/.htaccess` to deny all files and folders first:

```
deny from all
```

Then inside the folders you want to allow access i.e. `blog/css` or `blog/js`,  create a .htaccess file with this directive:

```
allow from all
```